# Replacing a line of code with an if statement

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've followed the here often recommended tutorial [Build a PHP MVC Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD) and I ran into a line of code that was a shortened if statement using `?` and `:`. Since I'm not really familiar with this kind of short code, I tried to recreate it how I would write it.

`$this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];`

I came up with:

```
    if(isset($url))
    {
      $this->params = array_values($url);
    }
```

Is this doing the exact same thing? Or am I missing something? It works and it looks like it's doing the same, but I'd like to know for sure.

Since some of the answers depend on the state of $url, here is the full code:

```
<?php
  class App
  {

    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
      $url = $this->parseUrl();

      if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php'))
      {
        $this->controller = $url[0];
        unset($url[0]);
      }

      require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

      $this->controller = new $this->controller;

      if(isset($url[1]))
      {
        if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]))
        {
          $this->method = $url[1];
          unset($url[1]);
        }
      }

      $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

      call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
      if(isset($_GET['url']))
      {
        return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `if($url)     {  $this->params = array_values($url);     } else $this->params = []; `

Comment: It's important to explain that the first code evaluates the content of `$url` checking for `true`. Your example only checks if the variable is set. And you didn't provide a solution in case that condition doesn't work(the `else`). Anyways, the correspondent would be like @splash58 already commented.

Comment: that format also translates to `$variable = $condition ? $value_if_true : $value_if_false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (isset($url))` will check for the presence of a set variable.

`if ($url)` will check for a truthy value from the variable itself.

You should use `if ($url)`

By the way, the code that's unfamiliar to you is called a [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)! It's common across a few other languages (e.g. Ruby) and it's useful to know how it works.

If you don't know what I mean about a truthy value, you should read more about [boolean casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: Won't `if($url)` throw an error if it wasn't declared before? Or was that only if you try to access arrays with it like `if( $arr['myUndefinedKey'])`. Sorry for offtopic question, could just try it out, but well, i wrote it now..

Comment: @lexith It will trigger a notice, but assume `NULL`

Comment: Thank you, just tried it :) Could it be that this wasn't the behaviour in older php versions like php 4 or sth? PHPStorm marks at as undefined as well, so this wouldn't be the very best practice. Which means wouldn't an `(isset($url) && $url)` actually be better?

Comment: @lexith PHP 4 will behave the same as well. It's obviously not good to do it this way but I am answering the scope of the question. If I were to rewrite the check, I would use `if (!empty($url))` which takes care of all of that, even undefined variables.

Comment: Thanks! $url has been declared before  `$url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL))` but you guys didn't know that. Sorry that my snippet wasn't relevant enough, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @sjagr thanks for the explanation. just to be clear, i didn't want to criticise your answer, i was just wondering :)

Comment: @lexith I understood your intent, no worries!

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct way is:

```
$this->params = [];
if($url) {
    $this->params = array_values($url);
}
```

Or

```
if($url) {
    $this->params = array_values($url);
}
else {
    $this->params = [];
}
```

It's called a ternary statement.  `[value] = [condition] ? [if true] : [else]`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `$this->params[]` is already defined in the class header (`protected $params = []`) (sorry for not posting full code, thought it was relevant enough), so I could just use the `if($url)` statement from your first example. Guess I just didn't have to use `isset()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's equivalent to :

```
 if(isset($url))
 {
     $this->params = array_values($url);
 } else {
     $this->params = [];
 }
```

Comment: Your reply almost matches to another comment, except for the isset(). (which isn't necessarily bad, thanks for thinking!)

Answer (score 1):

In `Php`  `isset` is used to check an `variavble` is `defined` or not. It just `return` `true` and false based on `variable` is define or not.

For more info about `isset` please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

On the other-hand `ternary` `opreators` are nothing but short form of `if-else` which are more convenient to write

`Ternary operators` are usedful when you have `multiple conditions` then instead of using multiple `if-else` you can use `ternary` like see this example

```
$data= ($value== 1) ? "one" : (($value== 2)  ? "two" : "other");
```

you can concate multiple condition in this

Comment: This is very useful for future encounters with ternary operators. I still feel the need to write the full if/else statement because I think that way it will be easier to read and if necessary, add code within the brackets later on.